# Selenium Webdriver Not Finding Element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm looking for this specific element:

```
<input tabindex="3" class="logintextbox user" name="USER" maxlength="255" size="25"
  onfocus="if (this.value == 'This is usually your email address') {this.value=''}"
  onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value='This is usually your email address'}"
  value="This is usually your email address" data-value="this is usually your email address"
  autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

using this snippet of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name(login_input).clear()
```

Where:

```
login_input == "logintextbox user"
```

But running this I continue to get a

```
"Unable to locate element: .logintestbox user"
```

in terminal. I don't see what I'm doing wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide some sample HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is two class names.  The method find_element_by_class_name will take only one class name at a time. Either the class  logintextbox
 or user. For example,

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("logintextbox")
driver.find_element_by_class_name("user")
```

If you want to use both class name then go with xpath or CSS selector as given below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='logintextbox user']")
```

Or

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".logintextbox.user")
```